# Split files in Unix by 100 files in a folder

Tags: macos, shell, unix

I am trying to split a folder of 10000 files into several folders of 100 files each inside the same folder. It will be a cut operation but not a copy operation. I tried one command but that counts folder as well part of 100 files.

Command i tried :

```
➜  ~  mv -- *([1,100]) ~/Downloads/Pics/<FolderCount>
```

Here i had to create a folder every time. I would be happy to have a list of folders in a sequence or any random folder name for all new folders created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this maybe - but test on a COPY of your files. Remove the word `echo` if you like what it does - at the moment it only says what it would do...

```
#!/bin/bash
ns=0   # number ofsubdirectory
nf=0   # number of files moved

# Loop through all files
for f in *; do
   # Skip subdirectories
   [ -d "$f" ] && continue

   # Generate subdirectory name and create it, if necessary
   sub="sub-$ns"
   [ ! -d "$sub" ] && mkdir $sub 

   # Move file and count
   echo mv "$f" "$sub"
   ((nf++))

   if [ $nf -eq 100 ]; then
      ((ns++))         # start new subdirectory
      nf=0             # zero filecount
   fi
done
```

Comment: Worked like a charm... :)